# Find the limit of the sum

Tags: calculus, limits

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{ k  (k + 1)  (k + 2) \cdots (k + m)
}, m\in\Bbb N$$

Please help to do this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{ k  (k + 1)  (k + 2) \cdots (k + m)
}=\lim_{n\to \infty}\dfrac{1}{m}\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{(k+m)-(k)}{ k  (k + 1)  (k + 2) \cdots (k + m)
}$$

$$=\lim_{n\to \infty}\dfrac{1}{m}\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{ k  (k + 1)  (k + 2) \cdots (k + m-1)
}-\frac{1}{   (k + 1)  (k + 2) \cdots (k + m)
}$$

Lot of terms will cancel, and you will be left with

$$=\lim_{n\to \infty}\dfrac{1}{m} \left[\frac{1}{ 1  (1 + 1)  (1 + 2) \cdots (1 + m-1)
}-\frac{1}{   (n + 1)  (n + 2) \cdots (n + m)
}\right] = \dfrac{1}{m\cdot m!}$$

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $$\frac{m}{k\cdots (k+m)} = \frac {1}{k\cdots (k+m-1)} - \frac{1}{(k+1)\cdots (k+m)}$$

Comment: Nice hint! +1 :)

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k(k+1)(k+2)\cdots(k+m)}=$$
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{\prod_{n=0}^{m} (k+n)}=$$
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{\frac{\Gamma(k+m+1)}{\Gamma(k)}}=$$
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{\Gamma(k)}{\Gamma(k+m+1)}=$$
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{\frac{1}{\Gamma(m)}-\frac{m\Gamma(1+n)}{\Gamma(1+m+n)}}{m^2}=\frac{\frac{1}{\Gamma(m)}}{m^2}=\frac{1}{m^2\Gamma(m)}=\frac{1}{mm!}$$